# Help! Pro Tools LE 8 in Sound Post-Production

Tags: pro-tools, purchase-advice, dvtoolkit

I make a post here because don't know anything about Pro Tools, I'm a Nuendo user, and want to take the next step to Pro Tools, but I don't know this is right or wrong... is Pro Tools LE 8 for post production? without the dv toolkit (it's really far from my budget) or I must stay with Nuendo...

I'm a student yet... but it's the chance to, in a few months, make the post for a indi movie, and I'm very exited about that...

Sorry for my english, I'm a spanish talker...

Enrique

Answer (score 1):

I've used PT 8 for post production for small projects. The limitations that I found hampering without the DV Toolkit is the smaller track count  (which I believe is 48 simultaneous voices) and no time code option in the counter (all you get is time with milliseconds and bars/beats), as well as the lack of continuous scrolling. Do you already have PT 8? These options are "unlocked" in PT9 (and you get more tracks, not sure about the scrolling). If you can manage without these functions,  you can still do post prod with PT8 (you may have to juggle tracks)

Comment: If you work in Europe then you're likely to work on 25fps footage and even though LE doesn't do timecode, milliseconds are fine (one frame at 25fps lasts exactly 40ms), just set the grid interval in accordance :)

Comment: I forgot to mention the  another thing. Depending on your workflow and how closely you will be working with the video editor, you may need the ability to import/export OMF files. This, unfortunately, is only available with the DV Toolkit (or digi translator) or PT9

Comment: Thanks dude! I know about all this limitations, but PT9 is too expensive here in Argentina, and the MBOX 2 (with PT 8 LE) is much more cheaper than MBOX 3 mini! Thanks for your answer! 

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help, but if you buy the download only version of PT9 (full version, or cross-grade from PT8 LE) from the Avid web store it can be much cheaper than buying it from a local reseller.

Answer (score 1):

As you are a student, you should be able to get the cheaper student version of PT9, which is probably identical in features to the full version.

With PT9 you can do all of the OMF/AAF importing and you also have proper timecode, even without the dv toolkit. You also get 96 audio tracks, which should be enough a lot of projects.

Whether or not you should make the transition to Pro Tools really depends on the community you are going to work with. Use the same program the others are using, this will make it much easier for you to exchange projects with others, as well as getting jobs in studios.

In the Danish film business, where I am working, there are roughly 0% Nuendo users and 100% Pro Tools users, so not being able to use Pro Tools would be pretty limiting for getting jobs here.

Comment: student version PT9 also comes with 4 years worth of free upgrades.. kinda cool..

Comment: Oh! I don't know anything about "Student version", it's a good option, but I don't know how to buy it... here in Argentina seems impossible to buy it, can I buy it from the net? thanks for your answer! and about Nuendo, it's a common soft in the student crew, but the pro's all use Mac's and PT!